# WinRt: Suspend and Resume - when should I release my resources and allocate it again?

Tags: windows-runtime, lifecycle, resume, suspend

My WinRt app implements a simple HttpServer. That server gets started when the app starts and should be terminated when the app ends. The HttpServer receives some callbacks from an other remote third party component. I need to register und unregister my HttpServer at the third party component.

My problem here is the Application lifecycle of an WinRt App especially the situation suspend -> resume (without Terminated or ClosedByUser).

In that situation the "OnSuspending" method is called while suspending, but nothing gets called when resuming.

In my App I unregister the HttpServer from the third party component during "OnSuspending".
The question is what gets called so I can reregister my HttppServer at the third party?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Since I found nothing for that situation, I did the following: At the "OnSuspend" I unregister my HttpServer at the third party component and create and start a DispatchTimer. The Tick event gets called as soon as the app resumed (and not in between). Within that Tick event handler I deactive the timer and restart my HttpServer and reregister it at the thrid part component. That works well so far.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Resume event, define it in your App.xaml.cs constructor

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Suspending += OnSuspending;
        this.Resuming += On_resuming;
    }
```

And write your Resume event

```
private async void On_resuming(object sender, object e)
{

}
```

Hope it helps